# How to check for every second and fifth position in a String?

Tags: java

This code prints yup to every second char (1,3,5,7,9..). Now I'm having a problem because I need also print a word for example *" yap "* to every fifth char (4,9,14,19...). So every tenth is *yup yap* etc... Appreciate if you have any hints or solution. Thank you for help!

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
    if( i % 2 != 0 && i > 0)   {
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " yup");
        System.out.println();
    }

    else{
        System.out.println(word.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `else if` statements like

```
else if (i + 1 % 5 == 0) {
    // for every fifth
} else if (i + % 10 == 0) {
    // for every tenth
}
```

and remove an unnecessary check `i > 0` in the `if` statement.